# 3 dots in matrix

Tags: symbols, matrices

I was wondering if anyone knew how to draw 3 dots in a matrix that go in a diagonal way usually to represent that element flow similarily in the slots. I know there's one that goes in the bottom right corner. But is there one that goes in the bottom left?

Comment: This might be useful: [How to look up a math symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Comment: @cmhughes: Interestingly enough, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) was my first stop after the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), and it was unable to give me any meaningful output.

Comment: @Werner: If I draw three dots, Detexify presents me with horizontal results, but clicking on "Select from the complete list" shows `\iddots` fairly high on the list.

Comment: @Jake: Argh... I didn't view the "complete list", that was my problem.

Answer (score 115):

For a good source to **math** symbols, I think the Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list is a  complement to the very good document [Mathmode.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). This document is interesting because it offers another organization and you can find all about mathematics.

[image]

Answer (score 33):

The [`MnSymbol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) provides `\udots` that prints 3 dots going from NE to SW; in the opposite direction of `\ddots` which goes from NW to SE.

Similar dots are provided by `\iddots` from [`mathdots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdots) and `\adots` from [`yhmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/yhmath). See p 60 of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). You could also use `\reflectbox{<stuff>}` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to reflect something about the vertical axis.

Here's a brief overview:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{yhmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/yhmath
\usepackage{mathdots}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdots
\usepackage{MnSymbol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol
\begin{document}
Different versions of diagonal dots:

$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \verb!\ddots! & \ddots \\
    \verb!\udots! & \udots \\
    \verb!\iddots! & \iddots \\
    \verb!\adots! & \adots \\
    \verb!\reflectbox{$\ddots$}! & \reflectbox{$\ddots$}
  \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

In addition to the above source of LaTeX symbols, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is also a fast way to identify symbols in LaTeX. Remember to "Select from the complete list!" if you don't see your symbol immediately, since the scoring algorithm may be off, depending on the symbol (or one's drawing prowess).

Comment: Do not use `MnSymbol` if you don't want to change the math fonts globally. `MnSymbol` is often overused. And note that `yhmath` is mainly designed for CM (or LM) fonts. `mathdots` and `yhmath` are both acceptble in most cases.

Comment: `\ddots` doesn't need any packages. Nor does `\vdots`…

Comment: @LeoLiu: Is it necessary to change math fonts globally in order to use the `mnsymbol` package? That's not something I've experienced so far...

Comment: @Mico: It is a little strange to use it with CM/LM fonts. This is explained at the beginning of the document of `mnsymbol`: “`MnSymbol` is a font of mathematical symbols designed as companion to Adobe MinionPro, but it might also fit well to other renaissance or baroque faces.”