# How to type dots whose slope is 1?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

We know how to typeset the commonly used diagonal dots, i.e., `\ddots`, whose slope is -1.

Now I want to produce dots with slope 1, which is perpendicular to `\ddots`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Perhaps the following is a little more general/comprehensive: [3 dots in matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32217/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MnSymbol` package provides a `\udots` macro, which does exactly what you want. When you're looking for some symbol, consult the [Com­pre­hen­sive LaTeX Sym­bol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/); you stand a good chance to find it in there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    diagonal dots ($\text{slope} = -1$) & $\ddots$ \\
    diagonal dots ($\text{slope} = 1$)  & $\udots$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your link of the symbol list. It is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `\iddots`?

It requires the mathdots package though.

EDIT:

There is a discussion on your problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/rotation-in-ddots)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on tools. If the package `graphicx` is acceptable, the solution may be as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\[
A\ddots B \scalebox{-1}[1]{$\ddots$} C
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to add `\mathrel` may be...

Comment: @HarishKumar Probably yes, but I understand, that OP asks only for a shape, without precising its usage.