# How to draw complex matrix?

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I want to draw a complex matrix like following. Tried several times but still didn't get it. Help please!
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that we can start with where you left off and have a better chance of helping you.  If you are having trouble getting started, [this question shows you how to use dots in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/3-dots-in-matrix).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `blkarray`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{blkarray,bigstrut}%

\begin{document}

\[ \makeatletter\global\setlength\BA@colsep{3pt}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}\makeatother
  \begin{blockarray}{(c<{\hspace{-0.95em}})}
    \begin{blockarray}{*{5}{c}}
      \begin{block}{*{5}{c} <{\hspace{1em}}\Right{\}}{$ x $}}
        0 & ... & 0 & ... & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
         ⋮ & ⋱ & ⋮ & ⋱ & ⋮ \\
        0 & ... & 0 & ... & 0\\
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}{*{3}{c}\BAmultirow{4mm}\BAmultirow{2mm}}
         ⋮ & ⋱ & ⋮ & \BAmulticolumn{2}{l}{\: \mbox{\Large$ A $}} \\
        \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\smash{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}0 & \mkern 1mu ... & \: 0\end{matrix}}_{\textstyle y}}}\\[-2ex]
      \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
  \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]